# VS Code with Vim extension: ctrl+d does not go half a page down but instead goes to "Select Environment"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked VS Code shortcut bindings, but do not see why "ctrl+d" will open "Select Environment" instead.  That does not even appear in the shortcut bindings. Any idea how I can make it go half a page down instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the Vim extension and expect it to page down.

If you select one of the environments (like Node.js for me), it should work after.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ever met this problem again, I solved this problem by entering command mode (press `:`) and `escape`.

I still am not sure what happened.